# Runtime Permissions

Tags: java, android

I am trying to take a screenshot by clicking a button with this code:

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        //openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I have this error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Thu Aug 29 10:42:39 GMT 2019.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I know that with API23 and later I need to implement runtime permissions, so here this code (using Dexter):

```
    private void requestPermissions(){
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
        @Override public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {openMultipleThings();}
        @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {}
    }).check();
}
```

On the emulator and the phone I get these permissions, and I also tried the way of recording the image, but still get this error.

Comment: You sure your image is with same name as you fetch it ?

Comment: make sure file path is correct

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu File path is correct.

Comment: @Abhishek Image name is correct.